# How to retrieve the text of a text label placed in a TileMap (.tmx)

Tags: libgdx, tiled

[TiledMapEditor](https://www.mapeditor.org/) supports the placement of text-labels nowdays, but I'm not able to load the text in a String.

I've tried iterating through the `MapProperties` of a `MapObject`, but the text is not part of them.

```
for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get("id of textlabels").getObjects())
{
  MapProperties props = object.getProperties();    
  Iterator<String> valueIta = props.getValues();
  while (valueIta.hasNext()){ 
   String currentValue = String.valueOf(valueIta.next());
   sout(currentValue); //prints id,x,y,width,height
  }
}
```

I also looked at the usages of the MapObject interface if there is anything like a ''TextLabelMapObject'' (like `RectangularMapObject`), but found none.

Looking in my .tmx file I can find this description of my object, but I have no idea how to parse that text attribute.

```
<object id="1594" x="1512.5" y="7170.5" width="83" height="19">
 <text wrap="1">Hello World</text>
</object>
```

My idea was to iterate through the layer's objects, parsing the current object to a TextLabelMapObject (which not exists) that implements a method getText() that returns the String inside `<text>`.

I'm a missing something here?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**:

So, as @bornander suggested I've created the following classes:

```
public class CustomMapLoader extends CustomBaseTmxMapLoader<TmxMapLoader.Parameters> {
```

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.java

```
public abstract class CustomBaseTmxMapLoader<P extends AssetLoaderParameters<TiledMap>> extends AsynchronousAssetLoader<TiledMap, P> {

//added to loadObject(TiledMap map, MapLayer layer, XmlReader.Element element) 
...
} else if ((child = element.getChildByName("ellipse")) != null) {
   object = new EllipseMapObject(x, flipY ? y - height : y, width, height);
} else if ((child = element.getChildByName("text")) != null) {
   object = new TextLabelMapObject(child.getText(), x, flipY ? y - height : y, width, height); //this line will create a text object with position data
}
```

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/BaseTmxMapLoader.java

so that I can load my map like this:

```
gameWorld = new CustomMapLoader().load(Constants.MAP);
```

Ans here is the `TextLabelMapObject`

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

public class TextLabelMapObject  extends MapObject {

    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private String text;

    /** @return rectangle shape */
    public Rectangle getRectangle () {
        return rectangle;
    }
    /** @return text as string */
    public String getText () {
        return text;
    }

    /** Creates a rectangle object which lower left corner is at (0, 0) with width=1 and height=1 */
    public TextLabelMapObject () {
        this("", 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    /** Creates a {@link Rectangle} object with the given X and Y coordinates along with a given width and height.
     *
     * @param x X coordinate
     * @param y Y coordinate
     * @param width Width of the {@link Rectangle} to be created.
     * @param height Height of the {@link Rectangle} to be created. */
    public TextLabelMapObject (String text, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super();
        rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

In my B2DWorldCreator I do

```
for (MapObject object : GameEngine.mapLoader.gameWorld.getLayers().get(Constants.LAYER_TEXTLABELS).getObjects()) {
  Rectangle rect = ((TextLabelMapObject) object).getRectangle();
  String text = ((TextLabelMapObject) object).getText();
  infoList.add(new InfoSign(main, text, rect.getX()/ Constants.PPM, rect.getY() / Constants.PPM));
}
```

with the InfoSign (thats later going to be a `Sprite`) being

```
public class InfoSign  {
    private String text;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public InfoSign(String text, float x, float y){
        this.main = main;
        this.text = text;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public void draw(Batch batch){
        main.assets.infoFont.draw(batch, text , x,y);
    }
}
```

[image: Lightheart Ed]

**Thanks a bunch!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `TmxMapLoader` that comes with **libGDX** then you won't get a `TextLabelMapObject` for your *Text*s, this is because that implementation does not cater for *Text*.

`TmxMapLoader` derives from `BaseTmxMapLoader` which reads objects in object layers using the `loadObject` method, which looks something like this:

```
protected void loadObject (TiledMap map, MapObjects objects, Element element, float heightInPixels) {
    if (element.getName().equals("object")) {
        MapObject object = null;

        float scaleX = convertObjectToTileSpace ? 1.0f / mapTileWidth : 1.0f;
        float scaleY = convertObjectToTileSpace ? 1.0f / mapTileHeight : 1.0f;

        float x = element.getFloatAttribute("x", 0) * scaleX;
        float y = (flipY ? (heightInPixels - element.getFloatAttribute("y", 0)) : element.getFloatAttribute("y", 0)) * scaleY;

        float width = element.getFloatAttribute("width", 0) * scaleX;
        float height = element.getFloatAttribute("height", 0) * scaleY;

        if (element.getChildCount() > 0) {
            Element child = null;
            if ((child = element.getChildByName("polygon")) != null) {
                String[] points = child.getAttribute("points").split(" ");
                float[] vertices = new float[points.length * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    String[] point = points[i].split(",");
                    vertices[i * 2] = Float.parseFloat(point[0]) * scaleX;
                    vertices[i * 2 + 1] = Float.parseFloat(point[1]) * scaleY * (flipY ? -1 : 1);
                }
                Polygon polygon = new Polygon(vertices);
                polygon.setPosition(x, y);
                object = new PolygonMapObject(polygon);
            } else if ((child = element.getChildByName("polyline")) != null) {
                String[] points = child.getAttribute("points").split(" ");
                float[] vertices = new float[points.length * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    String[] point = points[i].split(",");
                    vertices[i * 2] = Float.parseFloat(point[0]) * scaleX;
                    vertices[i * 2 + 1] = Float.parseFloat(point[1]) * scaleY * (flipY ? -1 : 1);
                }
                Polyline polyline = new Polyline(vertices);
                polyline.setPosition(x, y);
                object = new PolylineMapObject(polyline);
            } else if ((child = element.getChildByName("ellipse")) != null) {
                object = new EllipseMapObject(x, flipY ? y - height : y, width, height);
            }
        }
        if (object == null) {
            String gid = null;
            if ((gid = element.getAttribute("gid", null)) != null) {
                int id = (int)Long.parseLong(gid);
                boolean flipHorizontally = ((id & FLAG_FLIP_HORIZONTALLY) != 0);
                boolean flipVertically = ((id & FLAG_FLIP_VERTICALLY) != 0);

                TiledMapTile tile = map.getTileSets().getTile(id & ~MASK_CLEAR);
                TiledMapTileMapObject tiledMapTileMapObject = new TiledMapTileMapObject(tile, flipHorizontally, flipVertically);
                TextureRegion textureRegion = tiledMapTileMapObject.getTextureRegion();
                tiledMapTileMapObject.getProperties().put("gid", id);
                tiledMapTileMapObject.setX(x);
                tiledMapTileMapObject.setY(flipY ? y : y - height);
                float objectWidth = element.getFloatAttribute("width", textureRegion.getRegionWidth());
                float objectHeight = element.getFloatAttribute("height", textureRegion.getRegionHeight());
                tiledMapTileMapObject.setScaleX(scaleX * (objectWidth / textureRegion.getRegionWidth()));
                tiledMapTileMapObject.setScaleY(scaleY * (objectHeight / textureRegion.getRegionHeight()));
                tiledMapTileMapObject.setRotation(element.getFloatAttribute("rotation", 0));
                object = tiledMapTileMapObject;
            } else {
                object = new RectangleMapObject(x, flipY ? y - height : y, width, height);
            }
        }
        object.setName(element.getAttribute("name", null));
        String rotation = element.getAttribute("rotation", null);
        if (rotation != null) {
            object.getProperties().put("rotation", Float.parseFloat(rotation));
        }
        String type = element.getAttribute("type", null);
        if (type != null) {
            object.getProperties().put("type", type);
        }
        int id = element.getIntAttribute("id", 0);
        if (id != 0) {
            object.getProperties().put("id", id);
        }
        object.getProperties().put("x", x);

        if (object instanceof TiledMapTileMapObject) {
            object.getProperties().put("y", y);
        } else {
            object.getProperties().put("y", (flipY ? y - height : y));
        }
        object.getProperties().put("width", width);
        object.getProperties().put("height", height);
        object.setVisible(element.getIntAttribute("visible", 1) == 1);
        Element properties = element.getChildByName("properties");
        if (properties != null) {
            loadProperties(object.getProperties(), properties);
        }
        objects.add(object);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method tries to load `polygon`s, `polyline`s, `ellipse`s and texture regions, and if it's not one of those it falls back to assuming the object is a rectangle.

One way to solve this would be to create a new version of `TmxMapLoader` and have it derive from a new version of `BaseTmxMapLoader` and in that class extend the `loadObject` method to handle *text*s, possibly by adding a class called `TextMapObject` and modify the new version `BaseTmxMapLoader` to include something like this:

```
} else if ((child = element.getChildByName("text")) != null) {
    object = new TextMapObject(x, flipY ? y - height : y, width, height, child.getText());
}
```

[BaseTmxMapLoader on GitHub](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/BaseTmxMapLoader.java)